# Ruby hangman game - issue with overriding arrays (until loop)

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I am trying to make a hangman game in Ruby. Everything was going fine, but now I am stuck.

I have this code:

```
def feedback
  feedback = Array.new(@word.length, "-")
  correct_letters = []
  wrong_letters = []

  word_array = @word.split("")

  word_array.each_with_index do |letter, index|
    if letter == @input
      feedback[index] = letter
      correct_letters << letter
    end
  end
end
```

It sits in a loop:

```
until @@count == 0 || win?
  guess_whole_word
  user_input
  user_input_valid?
  feedback
  show_count
end
```

Every time the `until` loop executes, the array gets recreated so the values that were added to the array disappears. I want to add correct and wrong letters to the array, and also add correct the letters to the feedback which shows which letters that user guessed that create the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `feedback` function is instantiating new local array variables each time is executed.

If you wish to have access to those variables after the execution of the method, you can either:

- Return them as a result of the method and work with them in the `until` loop section:

  ```
  def feedback
    feedback = Array.new(@word.length, "-")
    correct_letters = []
    wrong_letters = []

    word_array = @word.split("")

    word_array.each_with_index do |letter, index|
      if letter == @input
        feedback[index] = letter
        correct_letters << letter
      end
    end

    return [feedback, correct_letters, wrong_letters]
  end
  ```
- Declare the variables as instance variables of the class so you can access them outside of the `feedback` method, but you would probably have to change your `feedback` implementation.

Comment: that is some idea, i will try to work with it and see how it goes

Comment: Good answer. Aside: I've had formatting problems when I have code following bullet points, sometime resorting to inserting the line `<p></p>`. I see you've simply indented eight spaces. Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yup, the information is the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists)

Comment: @Aegis thanks a lot, i declared them outside this method, and now everything works as it should. thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped you